# Linux Find Command

Tags: linux, command, find, wildcard

What am I doing wrong with the FIND command? I can't figure out why this works:

```
find /home/michael/foxpro/mount/A1/[12][0-9][0-9][0-9] "*.dbf" -type f -exec ln -s {} \;
find /home/michael/foxpro/mount/AF/[12][0-9][0-9][0-9] "*.dbf" -type f -exec ln -s {} \;
find /home/michael/foxpro/mount/AV/[12][0-9][0-9][0-9] "*.dbf" -type f -exec ln -s {} \;
```

but this doesn't:

```
find /home/michael/foxpro/mount/[A1][AF][AV]/[12][0-9][0-9][0-9] "*.dbf" -type f -exec ln -s {} \;
```

My folder structure looks like this:

```
...../mount/A1/2012/file1.dbf
...../mount/A1/2011/file2.dbf
...../mount/A1/2010/file3.dbf
...../mount/AF/2012/file4.dbf
...../mount/AF/2011/file5.dbf
...../mount/AF/2010/file6.dbf
...
```

The first script when I hard code the second to last directory the find scan through all my year directories but in my second script it just gives me a "No such file or directory" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern `[A1][AF][AV]` matches the following files/directories: AAA, AAV, AFA, AFV, 1AA, 1AV, …

To match the directories `A1`, `AF`, `AV`, use the pattern `A[1FV]` or `{A1,AF,AV}`.

Comment: {} was the key instead of [] when you have defined list of matches!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
find /home/michael/foxpro/mount/A[1FV]/[12][0-9][0-9][0-9] -name '*.dbf' -type f -exec ln -s {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem with find, it's a problem with shell syntax. Here's the problem:

```
[A1][AF][AV]
```

This gives you combinations like AAA, 1FV, AFV, etc. The bracket syntax matches one character in each group, it is not a choice between the groups.

In your case, I think this should work:

```
/home/michael/foxpro/mount/A[1FV]/[12][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with your regex.  What you have is this:
        /[A1][AF][AV]/ 
which will match AAA, AAV, AFA, AFV, 1AA, 1AV, 1FA, and 1FV.  What you really need is this, since each block [] of letters matches a single character:
        /A[1FV]/

Since each of your samples begins with the letter A, you don't need it in a [].